# PowerShell syntax highlighting bug with backticks

Tags: support, formatting, syntax-highlighting

Refer to [PowerShell Active Directory Browser](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55056/powershell-active-directory-browser)

Backticks are incorrectly interpreted as some sort of string, instead of a line continuation character.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't have a PowerShell syntax highlighter, because Google Prettify doesn't have a PowerShell plugin. What you see is the "best guess one-size-fits-all" default highlighter trying its best. There's an [open issue request](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=295) on Prettify that includes a plugin, but it's only a partial implementation. I'd be happy to include the PowerShell highlighter when it's complete, but until then the default highlighter (or alternatively no highlighting at all) is all we have.